# Why JsonParser is returning null?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, tree, json-deserialization

I have a custom `JSON Deserializer`, but it is giving some errors (the `TreeNode<Department>` is a Java tree structure class).

```
public TreeNode<Department> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    return parseDepartment(jp);
  }


 private TreeNode<Department> parseDepartment(JsonParser jp) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{
    JsonNode node=jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    if(node.has("name")){
      String name=node.get("name").asText();

      TreeNode<Department> n1 = new LinkedMultiTreeNode<Department>(new Department(name));

      if(node.has("department")&&node.get("department").isArray()){
        ArrayNode departments=(ArrayNode)node.get("department");

          Collection<TreeNode<Department>> backNodes=parseDepartments(jp,departments);
          if(backNodes!=null){
            backNodes.forEach(e->{
              n1.add(e);
            });
          }

      }

      return n1;

    }
    else{
      return null;
    }

  }
```

and another private method:

```
private Collection<TreeNode<Department>> parseDepartments(JsonParser jp,ArrayNode arrayNode) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{
    Collection<TreeNode<Department>> a=new HashSet<>();
    JsonNode node=jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

    // why here "node" is null?

    if(arrayNode==null) return null;
    arrayNode.forEach(e->{
      try {
        log.info(e.toString());
        TreeNode<Department> m=parseDepartment(jp);
        if(m!=null){
          a.add (m);
          log.info(a.toString());
        }

      } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    );
    return a;
  }
```

and when I run `test`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(TreeNode.class, new DepartmentDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

TreeNode<Department> n=mapper.readValue(json, TreeNode.class);
System.out.println(n);
```

the error is :

> java.lang.NullPointerException  --jp.getCodec().readTree(jp)

Comment: Can you please show the stacktrace?

Comment: @cricket_007 this is the error details : https://github.com/shell-software/tree/issues/2 ,thanks .

Comment: Okay 1) Your questions here should be self-contained, preferably a [mcve] 2) what is line 40 of the department parser class?

Comment: @cricket_007  thanks . I have resoled it just now  .

Comment: @KeryHu I am 4 years late to the party here, but if you resolve the issue yourself, you should post your resolution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to solve this too and you didn't post the answer...

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `jp.getCodec()` returns `null`.  Something like this worked for me.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(TreeNode.class, new DepartmentDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(mapper);
JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(json);

TreeNode<Department> n=mapper.readValue(jsonParser, TreeNode.class);
System.out.println(n);
```